# bootstrap col-md with panels of different height

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap panels to render some django objects on my webpage. I want them to appear by three. So I have created the following code

```
<div class="row">
    {% for account in accounts %}
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <!--panel with different body heights-->
            </div>
        <div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Because of panels being of different height they don't appear as I want them to, that is  3 in each row but bit randomly. I guess the solution is to put each triad in a seperate ".row" would be a solution correct?But that would take trying to calculate whether forloop.counter is divided by 3 and I don't like doing "calculation" on template since it's only for presenting data. Is there any better ways to achieve what I want?

Comment: `class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4"` can be simplified to just `class="col-xs-4" `. See https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E029

Answer (score 0):

unless you send the data in an array that contains sets of 3, you have to use a calculation in the template.

So you could send the data like this:

```
data[row1] = (col1, col2, col3)
data[row2] = (col4, col5, empty_obj)  # edit, added empty_obj to represent that you always need to make sure there are 3 items in the set or the template won't render correctly.
etc
```

then in the template you can do

```
{% for row in data %}
<div class="rowstart">
    {% for col in row %}
    <div class="column">{{ col.data }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

or simply use inside your forloop

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 or forloop.last %}
 <close row>
 {% if not forloop.last %}
 <open new row>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a css only solution.

```
.col-xs-6:nth-of-type(2n+3), 
.col-xs-4:nth-of-type(3n+4), 
.col-xs-3:nth-of-type(4n+5),
.col-xs-2:nth-of-type(6n+7), 
.col-xs-1:nth-of-type(12n+13) 
{
    clear: both;
}

@media (min-width: 768) {
    [class*="col-xs"][class*="col-sm"], 
    [class*="col-xs"][class*="col-md"], 
    [class*="col-xs"][class*="col-lg"] 
    {
        clear: none;
    }

    .col-sm-6:nth-of-type(2n+3), 
    .col-sm-4:nth-of-type(3n+4), 
    .col-sm-3:nth-of-type(4n+5), 
    .col-sm-2:nth-of-type(6n+7), 
    .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(12n+13) 
    {
        clear: both;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992) {
    [class*="col-sm"][class*="col-md"], 
    [class*="col-sm"][class*="col-lg"] 
    {
        clear: none;
    }

    .col-md-6:nth-of-type(2n+3), 
    .col-md-4:nth-of-type(3n+4), 
    .col-md-3:nth-of-type(4n+5), 
    .col-md-2:nth-of-type(6n+7), 
    .col-md-1:nth-of-type(12n+13) 
    {
        clear: both;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200) {
    [class*="col-md"][class*="col-lg"] 
    {
        clear: none;
    }

    .col-lg-6:nth-of-type(2n+3), 
    .col-lg-4:nth-of-type(3n+4), 
    .col-lg-3:nth-of-type(4n+5), 
    .col-lg-2:nth-of-type(6n+7), 
    .col-lg-1:nth-of-type(12n+13) {
        clear: both;
    }
}

// use .col-nobreak class to deactivate this fix
.col-nobreak {
    clear: none !important;
}
```

Show my post here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30037332/4863373

On Codepen i've created a pen to this issue:

http://codepen.io/valentinpalkovic/pen/PqPzzB